# segmentation fault when I use Pycaret

Tags: python, pycaret

When I try to use Pycaret on my MacOS, it stops and gives me this error:

> 10136 segmentation fault  python main.py
> /usr/local/anaconda3/envs/torch2/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/resource_tracker.py:216: UserWarning: resource_tracker: There appear to be 1 leaked semaphore objects to clean up at shutdown
> warnings.warn('resource_tracker: There appear to be %d ')

This error will also happen when I use `Lazypredict` library.

How can fix it?

Comment: Please provide an [M.R.E.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). As it stands, there is not enough information to reproduce or to debug your issue.